# Calling a function from another function in typescript

Tags: angular, angular7

I have called a function on `ngOnInit()` and now I am trying to call another function from the previous function but I am not able to get the results from second function

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
        let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.searchElement.nativeElement, {types: ['address']});
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', () => {
            this.ngZone.run(() => {
                let place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autocomplete.getPlace();
                if (place.geometry === undefined || place.geometry === null) {
                    return;
                }
                this.codeAddress(place.formatted_address, 'pickup');
            });
        });
    });
}

codeAddress(address: string, type) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, (results, status) => {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            this.getdistance();
        } else {
            alert('Request failed.');
        }
    });
}

getdistance() {
    console.log('get distance called');
}
```

Here in the code I am trying to call the `getdistance()` function from `codeaddress()` function. But it give me the error that `this.getdistance()` is not a function

Comment: Your code looks well . This is  one the way to call the function .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access `this` from within the callback you can use `function(){}.bind(this)` to make the function use the correct context, or use an ES6 arrow function.

```
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, (results, status) => {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        this.getdistance();
    }
    else {
        alert("Request failed.");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an arrow function instead of `function` to use `this` pointer inside of it.

```
codeAddress(address: string, type) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, (results, status) => {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            this.getdistance();
        } else {
            alert('Request failed.');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer pre-pending edit;

It's because you have a callback function with `function(){..}` instead of `() => {..}`. Thus your `this` is referring to the context of the inside of the `function` not the full class `this` scope.

Either change to an arrow function, or explicitly set `this` in the function:

```
var self = this
function(){
   this.getDistance()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

context of **`this`** is changed when you have goes into the function , So do something like below otherwise use Arrow functions of **`ES6`**

```
codeAddress(address: string,type) {
     const self = this;
     var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
     geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
           if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              self.getdistance();
           } else {
              alert("Request failed.");
           }
       });
  }
```